# Catching print dialog to limit the copies number (C#)

Tags: c#, printing, dialog, copy, try-catch

I want to know how and if I can catch when the user get a print dialog (in any application - word, chrome etc), and then limit the numbers of the copies.

I searched for 2 hours and found nothing.

Comment: Because user can install virtual printers, I guess it's practically almost impossible.

Comment: Yes, but this account is limited - Internet kiosk... So how can we limit it?